# PHP autoload can't use another folder

Tags: php

I have a problem with class. I have 3 folder , call them `one`, `two` and `three`. The `one` folder function like controller, `two` model and `three` view. I've made the autoload class in `two` folder (model layer) , but I can't call another class. My autoload.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

function __autoload($class){
    include 'two/'.$class .'.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

If I call autoload in index.php doesn't see another just what are in `two` folder so i can't call a method from one and three folder. How can I fix the autoload method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `spl_autoload_register` you can register multiple autoloaders. But a first approach would be register an autoloader that checks if exists `$class.php` in one of the folders (`one`, `two` or `three`), and include it.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $folders = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

    foreach ($folders as $folder) {
        if (file_exists($path = $folder. '/'.$className .'.php')) {
            include $path;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

But this is also a problematic approach. What if you had a `Foo` class in both `one` and `two` directory? Which you would import? To resolve these conflicts can use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/it/language.namespaces.php), and follow the directives of [PSR-0/4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).